# How to repeat a Regex 10 times

Tags: regex

I'm using the following regular expression in a web scraping program. It's scraping the html for a bulleted list but it's only grabbing the first bullet and leaving the other 9 behind.

How could I modify it to grab all 10 bullets?

```
<li>\s*<span\s+class=\"a-list-item\">(.*?)<\/span>\s*<\/li>
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Which lang are you runing?

Comment: How are you running that regex? are you running that from win, linux, etc? some additional info will help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [repeating multiple characters regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630982/repeating-multiple-characters-regex)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This is a pretty well formatted question, but there are others like it. [Consider looking at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630982/repeating-multiple-characters-regex) for additional information on doing repeated regexes.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with regex!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/418066)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With regular expressions, you can require a pattern be repeated a specific number of times with the `{}` characters. You can have as many groups as you want. So, you could do:

```
(<li>\s*<span\s+class=\"a-list-item\">(.*?)<\/span>\s*<\/li>){10}
```

(or if you need more or less, something like:

```
(<li>\s*<span\s+class=\"a-list-item\">(.*?)<\/span>\s*<\/li>){1,10}
```

(This answer assumes the rest of your string happens to be a legal regex for your regex interpreter. Modify as appropriate if not.)